# HTC One Messages app extremely slow, but just when I text one person!

Tags: sms, mms, htc-one

My friend (who texts me a *lot* of pictures of his kids) sent me a barrage of pictures and one video. Ever since then, texting him is excruciatingly slow. These things happen:

1. Just getting our text thread to open takes much longer.
2. When typing, some words get stuck and I have to wait until the word is completed.
3. When I do get the text written and hit send, the message disappears for a little while, then it appears, but as not sent yet, and then  after 30 seconds, finally sends.

Texting all other people is just as quick as it ever was.

I'm wondering if it's because I've got so many pictures in the thread? Can't think of anything else.

I'm deleting some pictures, to see if it helps, and I think I might try clearing the app's cache, but I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: Just tried clearing my Messages apps cache. When I click 'Clear cache' button. Nothing happens. However, it says my cache only has 52kb in it anyway...so... back to the drawing board?

Comment: If you're reluctant to delete the entire thread, you could (patiently) scroll back and remove some/all of the media he sent.

Comment: I did end up deleting the entire thread and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a small bug because it is specific to only one contact. Hoping you've saved all the stuff you want from that thread, delete the thread/whole conversation. If you don't mind delete the *contact* also by writing his number somewhere. Now start fresh again by creating the contact again and see what happens. Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.  After reading this question, I deleted the entire thread (which took my phone about 3 minutes) and it solved the problem.  What a relief.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue on my HTC One. Significant lag in a group text thread that has a lot of stuff (lots of messages and lots of pictures), and when texts are coming in, they're coming one after another.

Deleting the thread solves the issue until it gets big again. It seems like the app really struggles with a thread that gets too "heavy".